# Is there a way to compile with Java 7 in Scala IDE?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

I downloaded Typesafe's Scala IDE bundle, and now I try to make it work with my project, which uses Scala 2.9.2 and Java 7. My problem is, Eclipse still compiles it with Java 6, and I get those nasty errors about `javax.swing.JComboBox does not take type parametes`.

I'm launching eclipse with `JAVA_HOME` pointing to my `jdk7/jre` directory, and I added JRE 7 libs to the project. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** For some reason, it seems that only Scala compiler compiles with Java 6 - if I use plain `.java` file, it seems to be compiled with proper version. How could it be that Eclipse uses two different jdk's in one project?

Comment: Incredibly, there's no way to tell sbt which version of the Java libraries you need to compile your project against. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/how-do-i-configure-sbt-to-use-java-7. I asked again recently about this on the sbt mailing list and no-one replied, so presumably no change.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge - Well, that's exactly what I do when I work with sbt. But now I use Eclipse, and it starts sbt behind the scenes? Is there a way to influence which jre Eclipse uses when starting sbt?

Comment: It doesn't use sbt to compile, it uses some of the libraries to work out what to compile. Scala-ide uses the presentation compiler to compile.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell - So why those libraries still use java 6? Even if eclipse is started with java 7?

Comment: When you say 'the scala compiler compiles with java 6', do you mean that the class files generated aren't correct, or that the jars that you're using are incorrect, and still using the jdk 1.6 jars? IIRC correctly, the jars used are those in the project build path, so this should work.

Comment: In your project's properties, what is defined under Java Build Path and Java Compiler?

Comment: @MatthewFarwell - I'm using the correct jars, but it still complains that `javax.swing.JComboBox does not take type parametes`. Which indicates that it is using java 6, because those type parameters were added in Java 7.

Comment: @BrianSmith - In java build path - Scala-2.9.3-**, JavaSE-1.7. In Java Compiler - "Use compliance from execution environment 'JavaSE-1.7' on build path".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *eclipse IDE* is launched with whatever is the default JRE for your environment, like the one specified with the `JAVA_HOME`.

In this it's just like any other java application on your machine.

The jdk used to compile and run code within the ide is totally independent and it's defined within eclipse *preferences* under

**Java > Installed JREs**

You can add any runtime or sdk there and choose the default one used for new projects.

Additionally you can override this preference for each project within the *project properties*

In this way the compilation output is independent from your machine java environment, and can optionally be defined on a per-project basis.

As for the *Scala-IDE*, I need time because I don't have it installated on my day-job machine. I'll check later.

Comment: The problem is exactly that - I've already modified JAVA_HOME and friends, and plain Java code is compiled with Java 7. The only problem is scala code, that still seems to use old jdk.

Comment: On the release notes of [Scala IDE for Eclipse 2.0.2 RC1)() there's a note saying: **Better support for JDK 7** - 
The Scala presentation compiler used to (incorrectly) use the running JDK, instead of the one configured on the build path. Now it will honor the correct JDK, meaning that Eclipse can run on JDK 6, but your project can compile against JDK 7.

Comment: Can't say if that's related to your problem since you updated the JVM running eclipse. What Scala IDE version are you using?

Comment: "About" page says `2.1-M2-20120914-Typesafe`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't seem to find anything about this in the mailing list, maybe you should ask for help [there](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/scala-ide-user)