# Compilation failed: error while loading AnnotatedElement, ConcurrentMap, CharSequence from Java 8 under Scala 2.10?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using the following:

- Scala 2.10.4
- Scalatra 2.2.2
- sbt 0.13.0
- java 1.8.0
- casbah 2.7.2
- scalatra-sbt 0.3.5

I'm frequently running into this error:

```
21:32:00.836 [qtp1687101938-55] ERROR o.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine - Compilation failed:
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 10)
error: error while loading ConcurrentMap, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 61)
two errors found
21:38:03.616 [qtp1687101938-56] ERROR o.fusesource.scalate.TemplateEngine - Compilation failed:
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool tag 18 at byte 76)
one error found
```

Currently I'm running into this when simply trying to call a `.count()` on my MongoDB collection.

Upon Googling, it seems like it may be caused by dependency issues. The thing is, I'm using Scalatra just to serve an API and actually don't require any of the scalate stuff. I commented out all references to it, but I still get this. Could it be a dependency issue between the libraries I'm using?

Comment: Change to java 7 and try again. This is issue with java 8 and code which use scala 2.9

Comment: All the broken classes are part of the JDK, this seems to indicate that @ajozwik is right.

Comment: Have it been repaired ? I have a similar problem but I am working on scala 2.11.4 and Java 8 :(

Comment: Switch to 1.7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/setting-up-sbt-to-use-java-7-for-compilation

Answer (score 50):

In my company we had this problem with CharSequence. This is due to Scala 2.10.x does not work with Java 8. This was described in Scalas [mailinglist](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!searchin/scala-user/java%24208/scala-user/ttHT4lQRJGg). Switch back to Java 7.

Answer (score 12):

Switching to Scala 2.10.4 solved the problem for me.

Comment: How can that fix the problem. That is the particular version the OP claimed to be using

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem on Java 1.8.0 working with Scala 2.10.4 and sbt 0.12.4. But when upgrading to sbt 0.13.7, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 3):

I am seeing the same issue with software requiring Scala 2.9.2+ and Java 1.7 running on Scala 2.10.4 and Java 1.8. Changed to Java 7 via sudo update-alternatives --config java

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.2-RC2</version>
</dependency>
```

My environment is:

- JDK 8
- Maven
- Scala

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue in Ubuntu 14.04 but I solved by removing the scala 2.10 and installing 2.11

```
wget www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.11.7.deb
```

```
dpkg -i scala-2.11.7.deb
```

Now try.

Answer (score 0):

That was a lot of reconfiguration for me to get it to work,
here is my (NOW) working build.sbt using,
sbt 0.13.15 and scala 2.10.4 and jdk 1.8.1_131

```
name := "ScalaTelemetryManagerApi"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
scalacOptions := Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation", "-encoding", "utf8")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  Seq(
    "io.spray"            %   "spray-can"     % "1.3.1",
    "io.spray"            %   "spray-routing" % "1.3.1",
    "io.spray"            %   "spray-testkit" % "1.3.1",
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-actor"    % "2.3.2",
    "com.typesafe.akka"   %%  "akka-testkit"  % "2.3.2",
    "org.specs2"          %%  "specs2-core"   % "3.6",
    "com.github.seratch"  %%  "awscala"       % "0.5.+",
    "org.scalaz"      %%  "scalaz-core"   % "7.2.14"
  )
}

resolvers += "Scalaz Bintray Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"

Revolver.settings

retrieveManaged := true
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope a stable version of Scala will help you, Try 2.10.x with Java 1.7.x versions for better performance.

I mean it worked for me also in the same.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. However by switching to Java 7 my problem is resolved. 
So now this configuration works for me:

```
sbt 0.13.8
scala 2.11.7
java 7
```