# How to instruct gradle's scala plugin to pick specific JVM among installed ones?

Tags: scala, gradle, jvm, scalatra

I want to run scala compilation with specific JVM. I'm using Scalatra, and my default JVM is 1.8. With such setup, I run into this problem: [Compilation failed: error while loading AnnotatedElement, ConcurrentMap, CharSequence from Java 8 under Scala 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197836/compilation-failed-error-while-loading-annotatedelement-concurrentmap-charseq)

So I want to use JVM 1.7 for this, how to set it up for gradle "scala" plugin?

Answer (score 2):

> How to instruct gradle's scala plugin to pick specific JVM among installed ones?

This isn't currently supported. The best solution is to run Gradle itself with the desired JVM. It *might* be possible to instead set a different JVM bootstrap class path via...

```
tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    scalaCompileOptions.with {
        useAnt = false
        fork = true
        forkOptions.jvmArgs = [...]
    }
}
```

..., but you would have to figure out the details yourself (see JVM docs). Also you would have to know the JVM installation path.

Answer (score 0):

The scalac compiler has special parameters

> –javabootclasspath *path* 
>       Override Java boot classpath.
>   –javaextdirs *path* 
>       Override Java extdirs classpath.

You have to pass those parameters from gradle scala plugin using an ***additionalParameters*** parameter

this approach does not requires forking

```
allprojects {
  tasks.withType(ScalaCompile) {
    if (sourceCompatibility == '1.7') {
        scalaCompileOptions.with {
            def jdk7rt = new File("$System.env.JAVA7_HOME", "jre/lib/rt.jar").canonicalPath
            def jdk7ext = new File("$System.env.JAVA7_HOME", "jre/lib/ext").canonicalPath
            additionalParameters = ["-javabootclasspath $jdk7rt".toString(), "-javaextdirs $jdk7ext".toString()]
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I used this approach on my OS with JVM 1.7 as default for compiling with JDK8 some subprojects that requires javafx8. So it should work in your case.