# Migrate play 2.0 project to Play 2.5

Tags: playframework-2.0, migration

According to the Play documentation.

To migrate play 2.0 to play 2.5, I need to migrate 2.0 --> 2.1 --> 2.2 --> ... --> 2.5

So I started by

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration21

Follow this instruction,

I got the error:

```
error: error while loading AnnotatedElement, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar(java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.class)' is broken
```

According to this thread, [Compilation failed: error while loading AnnotatedElement, ConcurrentMap, CharSequence from Java 8 under Scala 2.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197836/compilation-failed-error-while-loading-annotatedelement-concurrentmap-charseq)

The above error was due to java 1.7 is required.

So here are the problems

On my Mac

1. I have java version "1.8.0_92" and I am running Play 2.5 which requires Java 1.8.
2. But to migrate Play 2.0 project to Play 2.5. I need first to migrate Play 2.0 to Play 2.1.
3. To migrate play 2.0 to Play 2.1, I need to downgrade my java to 1.7?

How could I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that multiple java versions on Mac are not a problem if you use Homebrew (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29195815/1502448).

If you don't want to change your java version, I think you would be ok continuing to follow the migration docs until you reach the first version of play that supports java 1.8 and then try to get it running.