# how to get more debugging for sbt compile error? "MethodHandle not found"

Tags: scala, sbt

Attempting to `sbt compile` a branch of my project [ENSIME](https://github.com/fommil/ensime-server/tree/lucene_refactor) (experiment if you're interested) under Java 6 is giving a bizarre compiler warning:

```
[info] Compiling 48 Scala sources to /home/fommil/Projects/ensime-server/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] Class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle not found - continuing with a stub.
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 18 s, completed 03-Sep-2014 22:57:44
```

It works under Java 7.

Calling `last` reveals nothing more than the classpath of the compile (this would be equivalent to setting `--debug` level).

I've removed all the plugins from the project, and the problem still shows.

If I remove all my code - leaving just the build system and dependencies - with some stub scala entry points then there is no problem.

However, I can't exactly bisect my source code file because then it doesn't compile.

When the code is compiled, a grep (including binaries) of MethodHandle doesn't give any hits (although there is a jdk8 file in the tests resources, it is not relevant because the problem appears if it is removed).

It is only one (big) patch that has caused the problem (the previous commit compiles ok).

1. **How can I debug this further in sbt?** it doesn't want to give any more info
2. is this a known problem, or can anyone make an informed guess what is going on?

Comment: The entire java.lang.invoke package was introduced in Java 7. Are you sure that sbt itself is running under Java 6? The [answer to this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/setting-up-sbt-to-use-java-7-for-compilation) may help to ensure that.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I use PATH, JAVA_HOME and check javaHome .

Comment: It's a bit tedious, but you can try to use the -verbose:class switch on the Java command line. (I do realize you want something higher level, but I also see that you don't seem to be finding it.)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was caused by pulling in Lucene, which requires Java 7.

A bit of an epic message fail from `sbt`: there doesn't appear to be any way to get it to output anything sensible.