# Scala - bad constant pool tag

Tags: java, scala, sbt, mapnik

I need to use this project https://github.com/dwins/mapnik2geotools . I proceed step by step, but when I enter `sbt run` I get this error :

```
C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\mapnik2geotools-master\mapnik2geotools-

master>sbt run
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
error: error while loading CharSequence, class file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\rt.jar(java/lang/CharSequence.class)' is broken
(bad constant pool tag 15 at byte 1501)
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I have installed scala 2.12.1. Any ideas?

Comment: Random guess is to use java 1.7 and/or scala 2.10. here is how to run it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/setting-up-sbt-to-use-java-7-for-compilation

Comment: So should I uninstall current scala and java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project is using scala version 2.9.1 (see build.sbt file) that was released long before java 8 came out. You seem to be running java 8. So you need to downgrade java to java 6 or 7.

Comment: can I have installed more than one java on my machine or should I uninstall jdk 8?

Comment: You can have multiple JVMs installed. But to avoid headaches due to configuration issues I would uninstall v8 and install jdk 6. Just keep it simple :-)