# Specify Java version in Java - scala mixed project in Intellij

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I have a project which includes both java code and scala code.

The structure looks like:

```
--src
   -- main
        --java
             myjavacode.java
        --scala
             myscalacode.scala
```

Now everytime when I run `sbt package`, the scala code will be complied in Java 7, but java code will be complied in Java 8.

I think I have specified the JDK to 1.7, but I still can not change java code back to Java 7 version.

What should I do in Intellij or build.sbt file?

Comment: Show us your build.sbt

Comment: build.sbt is nothing special. Should I have to add "java version" in the sbt file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*SBT* is pretty smart when it comes to *Scala*: you can specify which version of the *Scala* compiler and runtime libraries you want via the `scalaVersion` property, and *SBT* will download that version and use it to compile your *Scala* sources.

You can also specify the version of *Java bytecode* that is emitted by the *Scala* compiler through specifying the `-target` option in `scalacOptions` property. For example,

```
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.7"
```

However, when it comes to compiling *Java* sources, the currently selected *JDK* that you're using to run *SBT* is used. So if *Java 8* is your default version of *Java*, and that's being used to run *SBT*, then that's the version used to compile your *Java* sources - and I don't believe that there's anything you can do about that in your *SBT* build file except to complain if the current *Java* version is the wrong one.

However, you can specify a minimum *Java* version, then use the `-source` and `-target` options of the *Java* compiler to limit syntax and output to the version you require.

For example, the following works with any version of *Java* after version 1.7, but only compiles files adhering to 1.7 syntax, and outputs 1.7 bytecode:

```
// We need at least Java 7.
initialize := {
  val _ = initialize.value // Needed to run previous initialization.
  assert(scala.util.Properties.isJavaAtLeast("1.7"), "My project requires Java 7 or later")
}

// Configure Java compiler appropriately.
javacOptions ++= Seq(
  "-source", "1.7",
  "-target", "1.7",
  "-bootclasspath", "C:\\jdk1.7.0\\lib\\rt.jar"
)
```

Note that you still need access to a *Java* 1.7 runtime library (the location of which is specified by the `-bootclasspath` argument).

If that doesn't do the trick, then you'll need to specify the version of *Java* you want by changing *SBT*'s configuration. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/setting-up-sbt-to-use-java-7-for-compilation) for more details when running *SBT* from the command line. For *SBT* builds within *IntelliJ*, you'll need to specify the Project JDK to be used with *SBT*.

Comment: BTW, I should mention that if you're using _Scala 2.12_ then I think the _Scala_ runtime libraries will contain _JVM 1.8_ bytecode (that's not something you can change). If you want your programs to run on _JVM 1.7_, you'll probably want to use _Scala 2.11_ or earlier.