# how to avoid broken string class bug in macos?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a scala spark project that I am trying to run on my mac.

When I start the project in sbt I get the following output:

```
lpuggini-pro13:stackoverflow lpuggini$ sbt 
[residual] arg = '-sbt-create'
[process_args] java_version = '13'
[sbt_options] declare -a sbt_options='()'
[addMemory] arg = '1024'
[addJava] arg = '-Xms1024m'
[addJava] arg = '-Xmx1024m'
[addJava] arg = '-Xss4M'
[addJava] arg = '-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m'
[copyRt] java9_rt = '/Users/lpuggini/.sbt/0.13/java9-rt-ext-adoptopenjdk_13/rt.jar'
[addJava] arg = '-Dscala.ext.dirs=/Users/lpuggini/.sbt/0.13/java9-rt-ext-adoptopenjdk_13'
# Executing command line:
java
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss4M
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-Dscala.ext.dirs=/Users/lpuggini/.sbt/0.13/java9-rt-ext-adoptopenjdk_13
-jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/1.3.1/libexec/bin/sbt-launch.jar

[info] Loading project definition from /Users/lpuggini/ProgrammingProjects/spark_coursera/stackoverflow/project
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /Users/lpuggini/ProgrammingProjects/spark_coursera/stackoverflow/project/target/scala-2.10/sbt-0.13/classes...
[warn] /Users/lpuggini/ProgrammingProjects/spark_coursera/stackoverflow/project/CommonBuild.scala:3: trait Build in package sbt is deprecated: Use .sbt format instead
[warn] trait CommonBuild extends Build {
[warn]                           ^
[warn] one warning found
error: error while loading String, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home(java/lang/String.class)' is broken
(class java.lang.NullPointerException/null)
[info] Set current project to bigdata-stackoverflow (in build file:/Users/lpuggini/ProgrammingProjects/spark_coursera/stackoverflow/)
>
```

with error message
`error: error while loading String, class file '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-13.jdk/Contents/Home(java/lang/String.class)' is broken`

I think this is later causing a crash in the code

```
> console
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/lpuggini/ProgrammingProjects/spark_coursera/stackoverflow/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala 2.11.12 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 13).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._

scala> import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

scala> import annotation.tailrec
import annotation.tailrec

scala> import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

scala> val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("StackOverflow")
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/Users/lpuggini/Library/Caches/Coursier/v1/https/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-unsafe_2.11/2.4.3/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.3.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@33f9678b

scala> val sc: SparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
19/09/22 15:56:28 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.3
19/09/22 15:56:28 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
  at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3720)
  at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1909)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:50)
  at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:79)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.parseStaticMapping(Groups.java:116)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:93)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:73)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:293)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:283)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:260)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:789)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:774)
  at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:647)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:293)
  ... 42 elided

scala>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: I think the problem is that you are using a **JDK** 13, try with a **JDK** 8.

Comment: thanks do you know how I can change it?

Comment: just install the **JDK** 8 and change the `JAVA_HOME` env variable. You can find a lot of information on google about that.

Comment: so I have installed java8 with `brew cask install adoptopenjdk8`   but now I do not understand how to set the `JAVA_HOME`.  I have tried :`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/` but `sbt` is still using `java 13`

Comment: Not sure, I do not use Mac. It seems it has an special command for managing Java versions. Have you checked something like [this](https://medium.com/@bryantjiminson/changing-default-java-version-in-mac-os-x-yosemite-470f11a6084b) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21964709/how-to-set-or-change-the-default-java-jdk-version-on-os-x)

Comment: Might need to edit SBT launch script: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701692/setting-up-sbt-to-use-java-7-for-compilation

Comment: yes I think your last comment solved.  You may want to write an answer.